# Require regex pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How do I construct a regular expression pattern to read the text which starts with the below format in C#:

```
"Sec. 1.01."
"Sec. 1.02."
"Sec. 47.01."
"Sec. 47.06."
"Sec. 71.022."
```

Comment: Are the quotes part of your desired match? Depends heavily on what is around your target text too. In its current form, you *could* match this with ^".*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
"Sec\.\s\d+\.\d+\."
```

Is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd use `\s*` or `\s+` instead of just `\s`, just in case.

Comment: @Nolonar I'd do that too, but I don't know how tolerant he is with matching the whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sec\.\s\d+\.\d+\.
```

The above regex might do the work.

`Sec` matches exact Sec
`\.` matches a dot
`\s` matches a space
`\d` matches a digit (number)
`\d+` matches one or more occurrences of digits
If you want to match inverted commas as well, add `"` at the beginning and end of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

*Let's build a regular expression!*

First you want to match the literal text (including the whitespace). However, we need to escape the dot.

```
"Sec\. "
```

Then you want to match one or more digits. `\d` matches digits, `+` matches one or more of the preceding:

```
"\d+"
```

Then another dot, escaped again:

```
"\."
```

Then another sequence of one or more digits:

```
"\d+"
```

And finally another dot, escaped:

```
"\."
```

Put together this forms:

```
"Sec\. \d+\.\d+\."
```

If the whitespace between `Sec.` and the digits is not always a single space (e.g. possibly a sequence of spaces, or a tab), then you can use the `\s` whitespace class and the `+` to match it more than once (`"\s+"`):

```
"Sec\.\s+\d+\.\d+\."
```

If your regular expression would also have to match the start and end of a line, then `^` will match the start and `$` will match the end:

```
"^Sec\.\s+\d+\.\d+\.$"
```

And finally, if you use this in C# you'll have to prefix the string with an `@` to prevent C# from interpreting the slashes incorrectly:

```
string pattern = @"^Sec\.\s+\d+\.\d+\.$";
```

---

If you want to capture part of the expression, you can use a *capturing group* (written as `(?<name> regex )`. For example, to capture the numeric part:

```
string pattern = @"^Sec\.\s+(?<num>\d+\.\d+)\.$";
```

Now you can get the numeric part of the string:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
var match = regex.Match("Sec. 71.022.");
string num = match.Groups["num"].Value;
// num = "71.022"
```

---

You can find all this, and more, in the regular expression references:

- [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)
- [.NET specific syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(a, @"^Sec[.]\s(?:\d*[.]){2}$");
foreach (Match item in mc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Use `@` at the beginning of a string literal to avoid the need to escape characters. e.g `@"^Sec[.]\s(?:\d*[.]){2}$"`